# environment setup for hyperledger composer "npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer"?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

need step by step tutorials ?

I get the below error. Do i need to install dot net?

> 102024 verbose lifecycle hashtable@2.0.2~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
>       102025 verbose lifecycle hashtable@2.0.2~install: PATH: C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-hyperledger-composer\node_modules\hashtable\node_modules.bin;C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-hyperledger-composer\node_modules.bin;C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;E:\project\Maven\maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Go\bin;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
>       102026 verbose lifecycle hashtable@2.0.2~install: CWD: C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-hyperledger-composer\node_modules\hashtable
>       102027 silly lifecycle hashtable@2.0.2~install: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node-gyp configure build' ]
>       102028 silly lifecycle hashtable@2.0.2~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
>       102029 info lifecycle hashtable@2.0.2~install: Failed to exec install script
>       102030 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_locks\staging-021d018a547f4a2b.lock for C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging
>       102031 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
>       102032 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
>       102033 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
>       102034 silly install printInstalled
>       102035 verbose stack Error: hashtable@2.0.2 install: `node-gyp configure build`
>       102035 verbose stack Exit status 1
>       102035 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
>       102035 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       102035 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       102035 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
>       102035 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       102035 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       102035 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>       102035 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>       102036 verbose pkgid hashtable@2.0.2
>       102037 verbose cwd C:\Windows\system32
>       102038 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>       102039 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Mabel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-hyperledger-composer"
>       102040 error node v6.10.0
>       102041 error npm  v3.10.10
>       102042 error code ELIFECYCLE
>       102043 error hashtable@2.0.2 install: `node-gyp configure build`
>       102043 error Exit status 1
>       102044 error Failed at the hashtable@2.0.2 install script 'node-gyp configure build'.
>       102044 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>       102044 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hashtable package,
>       102044 error not with npm itself.
>       102044 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>       102044 error     node-gyp configure build
>       102044 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>       102044 error     npm bugs hashtable
>       102044 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>       102044 error     npm owner ls hashtable
>       102044 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>       102045 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Hyperledger Composer is not supported on Windows and although possible to make some progress in getting it working, it is not a trivial exercise.
I would recommend installing something like virtual box and then creating a VM to run a full linux distribution such as Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The official Documentation (See [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/introduction/introduction.html)) is the best place to learn composer. Hyperledger is a big community comprising of many projects (Read [here](http://hyperledger.org/)). I have also received hashtable error. I made a workaround by first doing `npm install -g hashtable@2.0.2` and then `npm install -g` of the composer packages.